# CompletableFuture re-use

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future

According to [Java 8: Definitive guide to CompletableFuture](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/05/java-8-definitive-guide-to.html) a CompletableFuture object can only be completed once. When I discovered it I had a simple interface in mind:

```
public interface Synchronizable<E> {

    CompletableFuture future = new CompletableFuture();

    default E waitFor() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        return (E) future.get();
    }

    default E waitFor(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        return (E) future.get(timeout, unit);
    }

    default void complete(E o) {
        future.complete(o);
    }

    default void complete() {
        complete(null);
    }

}
```

With the purpose of a thread being able to call `waitFor()` so that it would wait until another thread calls `complete()`.

Apparently it does not work that way. The first time a cycle like this happens it works fine however the second time; on a totally different class it does not wait and the `complete()` method of the CompletableFuture class returns false.

So I thought, alright it can only be completed once so why not create a new instance of it to "reset" it? I only use the value once anyways. That doesn't work. In fact it breaks entirely. When I attempt to create a new instance my program goes into a dead-lock!

The article also speaks about a way to pass on values without completing the future (`obtrudeValue()`). I tried this but it results in the same as the `complete()` method.

Is there something I can do to prevent this or an alternative that has the functionality I want?

Comment: _a new instance of it_ A new instance of what? Can you show a complete example?

Comment: You are using the wrong primitive for your class. A [SynchronousQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) is a better match.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis a new instance of CompletableFuture

Comment: @BenManes I have checked that out and I could probably use such queue :) thanks!

Comment: Please show how you do that.

Comment: @Limnic You can use `take()` if you don't want to timeout.

Comment: Please note that since your `Synchronizable` is an interface, your `future` field is implicitly `static final`. Hence the generic mess that you have, clearly showing that it is not type safe.